# Angular 5 too many geolocation position responses

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, geolocation, angular5

I want to write in Angular 5 component, function that geting me every 3 seconds my current location if it was changed.

My code looks like that:

```
export class WorkComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeCurrentPosition();
  }

  subscribeCurrentPosition() {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
      window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.myLocation = new TrackLocation(null, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          this.userService.sendCurrentPosition(this.myLocation, this.supplierId);  //send position to backend
          setInterval(() => this.subscribeCurrentPosition(), 3000);
        }, (error) => {
          LoggingService.error('Geolocation error: '+ error);
        });
      } else {
        LoggingService.error('Geolocation not supported in this browser');
      }
  }
}
```

I received location change in function subscribeCurrentPosition(), but problem is that every 3 seconds function is called more and more times 1, 2, 4.. 
It seems like every function call, calling 2 times next function.
And then I received alert that I send too many requests from geolocation api.

I don't know why function subscribeCurrentPosition() is calling more than one time every 3 seconds.
There is only one instance of component in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `setInterval`. Every time you use `setInterval`, you are creating a new task that will repeat indefinitely. And you are recursively calling `sentInterval` every time your function executes. That's why you are seeing these tasks multiply as time goes on. Use `setTimeout` instead. It will only execute once. And since you are using a recursive mechanism, it will continue to get called every time you receive a response:

```
  subscribeCurrentPosition() {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
      window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.myLocation = new TrackLocation(null, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          this.userService.sendCurrentPosition(this.myLocation, this.supplierId);  //send position to backend
          setTimeout(() => this.subscribeCurrentPosition(), 3000);
        }, (error) => {
          LoggingService.error('Geolocation error: '+ error);
        });
      } else {
        LoggingService.error('Geolocation not supported in this browser');
      }
  }
```

Or, you can use `setInterval`, but do it outside your function:

```
  subscribeCurrentPosition() {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
      window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.myLocation = new TrackLocation(null, position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          this.userService.sendCurrentPosition(this.myLocation, this.supplierId);  //send position to backend
        }, (error) => {
          LoggingService.error('Geolocation error: '+ error);
        });
      } else {
        LoggingService.error('Geolocation not supported in this browser');
      }
  }
  setInterval(() => this.subscribeCurrentPosition(), 3000);
```